# Шифр Цезаря

Tags: java, шифрование

Недавно изучаю программирование и язык программирования Java в частности, и вот столкнулся с проблемой. Шифр Цезаря. Необходимо реализовать в одном методе. Но шифрования не происходит, почему-то проходит цикл без шифрования и записывает введенную строку.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
public static void main (String[] args){
    String CapitalLetter = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
    String SmallLetter = "абвгдеёжзиклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэя";
    Scanner InputStringIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String InputString = InputStringIn.nextLine();
    Scanner CipherKeyIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int CipherKey = CipherKeyIn.nextInt();
    for (int i=0; i<InputString.length(); i++){
        char m = InputString.charAt(i);
            if (m == CapitalLetter.charAt(i)){
                System.out.println(25);
                int index = ((CapitalLetter.indexOf(g) + CipherKey) % 33);
                g = index;
                m = CapitalLetter.charAt(g);
            }
            if (m == SmallLetter.charAt(i)){
                System.out.println(35);
                int index = ((SmallLetter.indexOf(i) + CipherKey) % 33);
                g = index;
                m = SmallLetter.charAt(g);
            }
        System.out.print(m);
    }
System.out.println();
System.out.println(InputString);
System.out.println(CipherKey);
}
```

}

Comment: Вот вам пара статей с примерами в помощь: [Шифр Цезаря](http://code-inside.net/caesar-cipher/) [Шифр Цезаря (Реализация на Java)](http://cybern.ru/cezar-java.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

здесь я бы Вам посоветовал почитать про таблицу ASCII, вместо того чтобы создавать два массива куда Вы записываете алфавит. Если вкратце, то с помощью данной таблицы мы можем узнать код любой буквы и наоборот. Если реализовать это в коде, то будет так:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "ААА";
    int key = 1;
    String new_str = "";
    String d = "";
    int c = 0;
    int y = 0;

    System.out.println((int) 'Я'); // здесь узнаем код буквы


    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        c =  (str.charAt(i) + key);
        y = (c - 1040) % 32 + 1040; // 1040 - это код буквы А, 32 - это кол-во букв
        new_str += (char) y; // получаем букву по коду
    }
    System.out.println(new_str);
}
```

Здесь я взял только заглавные буквы, но если сделать для прописных, то нужно изменить формулу. 1072 - это код буквы а, 1103 - код буквы я

Answer (score 0):

Ну, у меня вот так получилось.

public static String encryption(String text, int step){
        String res = "";

```
    char[] textChar = text.toCharArray();
    char[] lCh = { 'а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ё', 'ж',
            'з', 'и','й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с',
            'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ', 'ы', 'ь', 'э','ю', 'я' };
    char[] upCh = { 'А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ё', 'Ж',
            'З', 'И', 'Й', 'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н', 'О', 'П', 'Р', 'С', 'Т', 'У', 'Ф', 'Х',
            'Ц', 'Ч', 'Ш', 'Щ', 'Ы', 'Ь', 'Э', 'Ю', 'Я' };

    for (int i=0; i<textChar.length; i++){
        int index = 0;
        boolean isNOTLetter = Character.isWhitespace(textChar[i]);
        if (!isNOTLetter){
            if (Character.isLowerCase(textChar[i])){
                while (textChar[i] != lCh[index]) index++;
                index +=step;
                if (index > 32){
                    index -= 33;
                }
                textChar[i] = lCh[index];
            }else if (Character.isUpperCase(textChar[i])){
                while (textChar[i] != upCh[index]) index++;
                index +=step;
                if (index > 32){
                    index -= 33;
                }
                textChar[i] = upCh[index];
            }
        }
    }
    for (char c:textChar) {
        res += c;
    }
    return res;
}**текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом**
```